# How to position elements in HTML

Tags: html, html-email

I am completely new to HTML. I am working on creating a template for emails in Action Network, however, I can not figure out how to position the elements I created. I would like the donate button to be in the middle and all of the social media links to be on the right, underneath the logo at the top. When I try to move the logos to the right, they end up being in the white area instead of underneath the logo. ANY help is appreciated. The code is below:

```css
#outlook a {
  padding: 0;
}

.ExternalClass {
  width: 100%;
}

.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
  line-height: 100%;
}

img {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

.image_fix {
  display: block;
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #404040
}

table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  a[href^="tel"],
  a[href^="sms"] {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    cursor: default;
  }
  .mobile_link a[href^="tel"],
  .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
    text-decoration: default;
    color: orange;
    pointer-events: auto;
    cursor: default;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  a[href^="tel"],
  a[href^="sms"] {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    cursor: default;
  }
  .mobile_link a[href^="tel"],
  .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
    text-decoration: default;
    color: orange;
    pointer-events: auto;
    cursor: default;
  }
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}

@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:.75) {}

@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1) {}

@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5) {}
```

```html
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #FFFFFF;width: 100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;">
  <center>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" id="backgroundTable" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #FFFFFF;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important; line-height: 100% !important; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;"
      role="presentation">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="border: 0;background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" role="presentation">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" role="presentation">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF; padding:10px 10px 10px;">

                      <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" role="presentation">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="600">
                            <div style="color: #383838;font-family: Arial;font-size: 16px;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;">
                              <center>
                                <img src="https://can2-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/email_templates/logos/000/029/586/original/centerrrr.png" style="max-width:1492px; width: 100%; margin: 20px auto" />
                              </center>

                              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

                              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/communityalternatives" style="background: #3B5998;color: white; padding: 10px; font-size: 15px; width: 15px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 50%;" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>

                              <a href="https://twitter.com/CCA_NY?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor" style="background: #55ACEE; color: white; padding: 10px; font-size: 15px; width: 15px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 50%;" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>

                              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ccalternatives/?hl=en" style="background: #C13584; color: white; padding: 10px; font-size: 15px; width: 15px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 50%;" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>

                              <b><a href="https://www.instagram.com/ccalternatives/?hl=en" style= "background: #1B4164; color: white; padding: 10px 20px; with: 10%; height: 5%; font-size: 12px; width: 15px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 25px"> DONATE </a></b>

                              <br>
                              <br>

                              <b><div style="color: #1B4164;font-family: Arial;font-size: 14px;line-height: 125%;text-align: center;"> Center for Community Alternatives</div></b>
                              <div style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 14px;line-height: 125%;text-align: center;"> <a href="https://www.communityalternatives.org/">communityalternatives.org </a>

                              </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 2px solid #909090; border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" role="presentation">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" role="presentation">
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" valign="middle" style="border-collapse: collapse;background-color: #FFFFFF;border-top: 0;">
                            <div style="color: #707070;font-family: Arial;font-size: 11px;line-height: 125%;text-align: left;">
                              Sent via <a href="http://actionnetwork.org">ActionNetwork.org</a>. To update your email address or to stop receiving emails from [your group name], please <a href="[unsub link]" style="color: #0096DB;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;">click here</a>.

                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
  </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're _creating_ a template so much as modifying one. There's a lot of old technique and obsolete elements in there. Browser sniffing is a dated strategy, and the `center` element is deprecated. Line breaks shouldn't be used for layout spacing. That's what margin and padding are fore. All those spacing attributes on the body tag are also outdated. I'd consider starting fresh, or at least from a more modern layout.

Comment: But, to attempt a general answer, look into adding more rows and cells in the table to position your items. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics.

Comment: This is HTML email where we use deprecated features all the time! It's 1990's style with a few mobile additions!

Answer (score 0):

A `<table>` approach is the right way for HTML email, mostly for Outlook desktop's sake.

You don't need `<div>s` since you already have a block level element for positioning and styles: the `<td>`. Put all the styles on the div in the containing `<td>`.

You can do block-level centering with `<center>` tag, or the align attribute, and inline/text-level centering with `text-align` (on the closest block-level parent is best). (Lookup online about block vs inline, it's very important. e.g. https://www.samanthaming.com/pictorials/css-inline-vs-inlineblock-vs-block/)

For ease and consistency, place each row on a new `<tr>` (table row), and then in the `<td>` (table data), which always comes inside a row, set your desired padding. (Margins don't work across all email clients.)

Then you can set, e.g. your social media to the right like so:

```
<tr>
  <td align="right">
    <!-- Social media icons -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

And your donate button on next line like so:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center">
    <!-- Donate button -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

To get them on the same line, use two `<td>s` in the same row, with desired widths and alignments.

Btw what you have in the `<style>` part is good. Those reset a few problems in various email clients. Keep researching, but remember HTML email is different because many email clients are pretty backwards.

Comment: Hello Nathan, thank you for the help. I was able to make the buttons on different rows, but using two <td>'s I was still unable to get them both on the same line in the positions that I wanted the. Exaclty what did you mean when you said "use two <td>s in the same row?

Comment: Should be something like this (untested): `<tr><td align="center" width="80%"><!--Donate button--></td><td align="right" width="20%"><!--Social media icons--></td></tr>`